# How to combine tables in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have four tables in an Excel Sheet, two of them contain the uid & rank of the user whereas the other two contain marks and the uid of the user.

The output I want to achieve is 3 tables that contains the uid, rank and marks respectively of the user all in one sheet. I have a total of 10,000 entries in each table so I need a formula that is efficient enough for the operation.

Can anybody please help m e out as to how to go about this?

[image]

Comment: Can you have the first table(rank/uid) have the uid first and the rank after? Or should it stay like this?

Comment: No any order as fine as long as they are sorted @GeorgeMenoutis

Comment: Depending on your software version, you could use XLOOKUP or otherwise INDEX/MATCH as suggested. This could also be done with VLOOKUP but this would provide the worst recalculation performance of the three.

Comment: try google **Using PowerQuery to merge table** if you are using Excel 2013 or later versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into how to use index() and match()

index will be over your data, and then match the row and column of uid and dataheader respectively

```
=index(range(sheets(1).cells(2,1),sheets(1).cells(5,2)), _
match(sheets(2).cells(2,1), range(sheets(1).cells(2,1),sheets(1).cells(5,1)),0), _
match(sheets(2).cells(1,2), range(sheets(1).cells(1,1),sheets(1).cells(1,2)),0))
```

Bit ugly, but hopefully you get the idea. Output data would be in Sheets(2) from row 2 down (with headers in Sheets(2) row 1).

Input is an example assuming your top left in image presented starts in cells(1,1) on Sheets(1)

Or to describe each

```
=index(range of source data, _
match(destinationRowID, range of row IDs on source, 0), _
match(destinationColID, range of col IDs on source, 0))
```

destinationRowID here would be whatever the UID is
destinationColID would be UID, Rank or Marks

Because you've separate source tables, you'll have to include separate formula in some of your destination sheet columns

Comment: Could you show an example please @Amiga500

Comment: Thanks for the example however this is very complicated to understand @Amiga500

Answer (score 0):

XLOOKUP worked really well for me, thanks for the recommendation @ed2

```
=XLOOKUP (lookup, lookup_array, return_array, [not_found], [match_mode], [search_mode])
```